# Time complexity of python dictionary get() update() always O(1)?

Tags: python, dictionary, time-complexity, big-o

If I use only strings with maximum length of 15 as keys for a dictionary in python, is it impossible to have any collisions?

Worst case seems to be O(N) for accessing or updating a value, with N being the number of keys in the dictionary. With the built in string hash of python it's impossible to have same hashes on two different strings with maximum length of 15 and the worst case would be O(1), right?

Or do I understand something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well since there are a constant number of strings with length 15, there is no real notion of "big oh", since big oh deals with *asymptotic complexity*.

Comment: If you have a fixed number of strings then *by definition* everything is O(1).

Comment: Anyway, the complexity is *amortized* time. Given that `dict`s are dynamically sized when you insert too many strings the `dict` resizes. You *will* have collisions because the number of possible slots will be small compared to the number of possible strings. But you are mistaken that you'll end up having billions of strings in the same slot... python will resize the dict way before that. You will have troubles with RAM size before that, independently of your RAM capacity.

Comment: I mean the keys are all strings of different lengths, around 50 000 different keys in total. But they never contain more than 15 characters. What I mean is: can I expect all of these 50 000 keys to have unique hashes (since they use the built in hash) and so access and update the values (which are NO strings) with O(1)?

Comment: @JanB: well the same argument. All strings of a length at most 15 characters is a finite number, hence the concept of time complexity is more or less "non-existing" in the sense that even if you need to iterate over millions of keys, that is still constant time. Since the number of "keys" is fixed, it does not matter what values you change, the iteration is constant, although it can take ages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I use only strings with maximum length of 15 as keys for a dictionary in python, is it impossible to have any collisions?

**No**. Collisions *can* happen. The result of the hash function is truncated according to the "host system". So that means that the `hash(..)` of a string on a 32-bit system is 32-bit integer, and for a 64-bit system, it usually is a 64-bit number.

Now if we count the number of strings less than or equal to 15 characters (and we here will only assume printable ASCII characters, but if we consider all unicode characters, we only make it worse), then that means we can generate:

```
15
---
\             i
/     (128-32)
---
i=0
```

different strings. Which is equal to 547'792'552'280'497'574'758'284'371'041, or approximately 5.47×10<sup>29</sup>. The number of 64-bit numbers is 2<sup>64</sup>=18'446'744'073'709'551'616≈1.84×10<sup>19</sup>. So even if we only consider *ASCII printable strings*, then we can not map every string to a separate hash.

As a result, that means that hash collisions *will* happen if we keep filling the dictionary with new strings (eventually). Even if the dictionary creates one bucket per hash code, multiple strings will get in the same bucket, because the "hash space" is smaller than the "string space".

> Worst case seems to be *O(N)* for accessing or updating a value, with *N* being the number of keys in the dictionary. With the built in string hash of python it's impossible to have same hashes on two different strings with maximum length of 15 and the worst case would be *O(1)*, right?

It is **O(1)** but due to another reason. Since the number of strings has at most 15 characters, that means that the number of possible strings (hence keys) is *fixed*. For example the number of ASCII printable keys is fixed to the number we derived above (5.47×10<sup>29</sup>). Yes, we can use unicode, and this will scale up the number of keys dramatically, but it is still finite (well it is approximately 5.06×10<sup>90</sup>).

That means that means that there is an **upperbound for *N***, and therefore there is not really such thing as *assymptotic complexity*. Even if we manage to generate all these strings, and in the worst case these all map to the same hash code, and therefore all are stored in the same bucket, it is still constant time, the processor will have a very hard time iterating over the bucket, but it will still be constant: at most 5.06×10<sup>90</sup> iterations.